# Nested switch/case inside while loop and !Console.KeyAvailable C#

Tags: c#, while-loop, switch-statement, keypress, encoder

I am currently working on a project that utilizes encoders to track the position of a series of lead screws. This code block is being used to grab the position of each encoder and display it to the user with a while loop (no key pressed), as well as also giving them the option to reset any of the three positions to zero (by pressing either 'x', 'y' or 'z' on the keyboard).

As is, the user would need to press the 'x' key once to zero the x-position, press the 'y' key 2 times to zero the y-position, the 'z' key 3 times to zero the z-position and 4 times to end the program. The number of times the key needs to be pressed in order for the switch/case to happen corresponds to where it falls numerically in the list of cases. However, **I need is for each key to be pressed only once for the action to take place. How would I go about fixing the switch/case structure (or whatever else) to make that happen?**

Also, it does not seem to like the !Console.KeyAvaible in the first switch statement to check if a key has been pressed. The error is "cannot convert bool to System.ConsoleKey" Is there another way to phrase this?

```
while (true){
     long Position0 = encoder0.Position;
     long Position1 = encoder1.Position;
     long Position2 = encoder2.Position;
     ConsoleKeyInfo input = Console.ReadKey();
     switch (input.Key){
          case !Console.KeyAvailable:
               // initialize encoder positions and do math to convert to mm 
               float Position0f = Convert.ToSingle(Position0);
               float Position1f = Convert.ToSingle(Position1);
               float Position2f = Convert.ToSingle(Position2);
               float LinearPosition0 = Position0f / 400;
               float LinearPosition1 = Position1f / 400;
               float LinearPosition2 = Position2f / 400;

               Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
               Console.WriteLine("x Position: {0:0.0000##} mm", LinearPosition0);
               Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1);
               Console.WriteLine("y Position: {0:0.0000##} mm", LinearPosition1);
               Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
               continue;

               default:
                    switch (input.Key){
                         case ConsoleKey.X:
                              Console.WriteLine("\nYou selected X!");
                              Position0 = 0;
                              break;

                         case ConsoleKey.Y:
                              Console.WriteLine("\nYou selected Y!");
                              Position1 = 0;
                              break;

                         case ConsoleKey.Z:
                              Console.WriteLine("\nYou selected Z!");
                              Position2 = 0;
                              break;

                         case ConsoleKey.Escape:
                              Console.WriteLine("\nYou selected Esc! Exiting program.");
                              break;

                         default:
                              break;
                    }
               break;
}

}
```

In addition to the problem with the keys, the position displayed in the first if statement does not change. Where should I initialize the Position0/1/2 so that they can be reset to zero in the second if statement while still being updated every loop in the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if a key is available before reading a key, for example:

```
  long Position0 = 0;
  long Position1 = 0;
  long Position2 = 0;
  bool isEnd = false;
  while ( !isEnd )
  {
    Position0 = encoder0.Position;
    Position1 = encoder1.Position;
    Position2 = encoder2.Position;
    //Position0++; Position1++; Position2++;
    float LinearPosition0 = Convert.ToSingle(Position0) / 400;
    float LinearPosition1 = Convert.ToSingle(Position1) / 400;
    float LinearPosition2 = Convert.ToSingle(Position2) / 400;
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
    Console.WriteLine("x Position: {0:0.0000##} mm", LinearPosition0);
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1);
    Console.WriteLine("y Position: {0:0.0000##} mm", LinearPosition1);
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
    Console.WriteLine("z Position: {0:0.0000##} mm", LinearPosition2);
    if ( Console.KeyAvailable )
      switch ( Console.ReadKey(true).Key )
      {
        case ConsoleKey.X:
          Console.WriteLine("\nYou selected X!");
          Position0 = 0;
          break;
        case ConsoleKey.Y:
          Console.WriteLine("\nYou selected Y!");
          Position1 = 0;
          break;
        case ConsoleKey.Z:
          Console.WriteLine("\nYou selected Z!");
          Position2 = 0;
          break;
        case ConsoleKey.Escape:
          Console.WriteLine("\nYou selected Esc! Exiting program.");
          isEnd = true;
          break;
      }
  }
```

You can also hide the cursor if needed.

```
Console.CursorVisible = false;
```

[Animated GIF](https://www.ordisoftware.com/files/stack-overflow/EncoderResetLoop.gif)

Comment: Yes, the idea is that it prints the positions over and over again until it is triggered to do something else with a keypress. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: So I have finally gotten around to playing with your suggestions, Oliver. However, the zeroing part is not changing the positions printed in the first if statement. I'm assuming that is because the position = 0 is not connecting to the position given by the encoder in the first if statement. What would be the best way to bring that value down? I know that the second if statement is working because it still prints out the WriteLine().

Comment: I added an amendment to this question to give more information. Originally I thought it would help to simplify my code for the purposes of asking this question, but I realize now that might not have been a good idea. Thank you so much for your help and patience with me--I am a newly graduated mechanical engineer and they threw me into the programming for the mechanical rig I designed--so I am way out of my element with this.

Comment: Hiding the cursor was a great suggestion--having it flicker all the time was distracting. The position is still not zeroing out for me on my end, which doesn't really make sense. I'll keep playing with it. Everything else worked out great though. Thank you again for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: NEVERMIND I figured out what it was--everything is all squared away. THANK YOU!